# Removing a Specific Animation in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So, I want to use a Codrops resource in one of my websites and was wondering if there was a way to remove the animation where the text comes back up.

Here's what I'm referring to:

Visit this page:
http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/index.html

Then, scroll down to 'Madoka'

No, click on 'Frequency', 'Weight' or 'Style'

There'll be an animation where the text goes down to the bottom left corner.

Don't type anything. Click off the text box.

Now, there should be an animation and the text will come back to where it was.

I don't want it to come back to where it was. I just want the text to stay at the bottom right corner once the user clicks on it.

You can find the source files here:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/01/08/inspiration-text-input-effects/

Thanks For Helping Me Out,
MarshyM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following from `index.html` line 370 in source:

```
        function onInputBlur( ev ) {
            if( ev.target.value.trim() === '' ) {
                classie.remove( ev.target.parentNode, 'input--filled' );
            }
        }
```

And remove from `index.html` line 363:

```
inputEl.addEventListener( 'blur', onInputBlur );
```

Comment: That was very quick. Thank You so much!

Comment: @MarshyM please up vote and accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Done. Many thanks for your help. Although I am new here and cannot upvote publicly yet.